# What is happening in this C/Arduino code?

Tags: arduino

I'm new to C and Arduino development and wondering what's going on here. The code is supposed to print the response from an HTTP request, but instead it cuts off after around 300 bytes.

```
static void my_callback (byte status, word off, word len) {
  Ethernet::buffer[off+300] = 0; // <--
  Serial.print((const char*) Ethernet::buffer + off); // <--
}
```

In Javascript, `Ethernet::buffer[off+300] = 0` would mean you're assigning a value of `0` to something in an object or array, at position `[off+300]`. Why is this being done here *before* the result is returned, or at all?

Next, the value of `Ethernet::buffer` is added to the value of `off` (which is a number). So the result should be a number, but instead it's a string.

Any insight into what is going on here would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Source: [EtherCard examples](https://github.com/jcw/ethercard/blob/master/examples/webClient/webClient.ino)

Comment: This isn't C, could be C++.

Comment: In order to read this code, you need to understand pointers and pointer arithmetic. Start learning [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @Lundin: Arduino is not exactly C++ either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment of `0` makes sure the string is terminated at 300 characters after `off`. In C and C++ basic strings are represented as arrays of characters, and use a character with the value `0` to indicate end of string.

This can be a protection against printing too much on the console, for instance.

The addition on the `print` line is pointer arithmetic, it's not "a number" (or, under the hood of course it's a number, that's all computers deal with, but semantically there's a difference). Adding a number to the address of a string in C (and C++, here) gets you the suffix, i.e. it skips that many characters into the string.